# My graduation rose is sprouting, help!

Tags: propagation, roses

So its been about a month and a week since I got the single rose and the rose itself is dried I think, but on the stem three little baby stems are sprouting new leaves. 
I've read up a bit about this topic but I have a question about what to do with the rose itself. I'm planning on leaving the stem in water, but since I got the rose from my school at graduation, I wanted to save it. 
Is it possible for the stem to still grow if I cut the rose off? 
Also any tips on how to care for it and how to get it to grow roots? I don't do a lot of gardening so suggestions that are simple and cheap would be great!

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/16320/my-long-stemmed-rose-is-growing-new-leaves?

Comment: Not really. I want to know whether its safe or not to cut off the rose so I can keep it. Any other advice would be great but its not the main focus

Comment: Lily, congratulations on your graduation! You have a two-in-one question here. For the first part (“Is it ok to cut the flower?”), see the answer below. The second part (“How to root the stem?”) is a duplicate of https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/16320/my-long-stemmed-rose-is-growing-new-leaves, as already stated.

Answer (score 1):

Cut that rose off of the mother plant.  ASAP.  It won't be pretty but you most certainly can dry and keep this rose as a memento.  Hang it up to dry out of the sun in a warm room. Or, you could go to an art and crafts store to purchase silica.  Nestle that rose into the silica and it will dry and look just like it is right now.  Hung to dry as an old rose or old flower means it will probably shatter.  A box of silica lasts forever if you are interested in drying flowers the most perfect way to dry and preserve flowers...silica.  Very much fun and very easy to learn to do.

Comment: Ugh, you are right, Stephie.  Should I just delete the rest of this answer?  She's got this rose with a stem in a glass of water?  Thanks, sighs!